# How to make Mathematica output updated Graphics inside Manipulate?

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, tooltip

I have created a code to get information about countries. I created a tooltip to identify cities on a graphics but when I go through the popup menu and click another country, the code doesn't reevaluate the points to label new cities.

```
Manipulate[

 Graphics[{Gray, CountryData[Country, "Polygon"], PointSize[Large], 
   Red, Tooltip[Point[Reverse[CityData[#, "Coordinates"]]], 
      CityData[#, "Name"]] & /@ 
    CityData[{Large, Country}]}], {{Country, "Afghanistan"}, 
  Dynamic[CountryData[], SynchronousUpdating -> True], 
  ControlType -> PopupMenu},

 Style["Full Name", FontFamily -> "American Typewriter", 
  FontSize -> 15],
        Panel[Dynamic[CountryData[Country, "FullName"]]],
         Style["Area", FontFamily -> "American Typewriter", 
  FontSize -> 15],
        Panel[Dynamic[CountryData[Country, "Area"]]],
    Style["Population", FontFamily -> "American Typewriter", 
  FontSize -> 15],
        Panel[Dynamic[CountryData[Country, "Population"]]],
    Style["Flag", FontFamily -> "American Typewriter", FontSize -> 15],
          Panel[Dynamic[CountryData[Country, "Flag"]]], 

 Style["Coordinates", FontFamily -> "American Typewriter", 
  FontSize -> 15],
                 Panel[Dynamic[CityData["Chicago", "Coordinates"]]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using county entities in `CityData` does not work:

```
CityData[{Large, Entity["Country", "Austria"]}]
```

need to use:

```
CityData[{Large, "Austria"}]
```

Here is a small example of corrected code:

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[
  { Gray, CountryData[Country, "Polygon"], 
    PointSize[Large], Red, 
    Tooltip[
      Point[Reverse[CityData[#, "Coordinates"]]], 
      CityData[#, "Name"]
    ] & /@ CityData[{Large, Country["Name"]  (*!!!*)}]}
  ],
 {{Country, Entity["Country", "Afghanistan"] (*!!!*)}, CountryData[], ControlType -> PopupMenu}
 ]
```